generating function of recursion with a hyperbolic function
I am looking to solve a recursion for a certain sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ through its generating function
$$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n x^n\tag{1}\label{1},$$
which after plugging-in the specific recursion rule for my problem and some calculations gives the relation:
\begin{equation}
f' = f +f \coth(f)-1,
\end{equation}
where $f'$ denotes the derivative of $f$ and where indeed the hyperbolic functions $\coth$ occurs.
I then proceed to the integration of
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{df}{f +f \coth(f)-1}= \int dx
\end{equation}
which yields
\begin{equation}
\log \big[f e^f - \sinh(f)\big] - f  =2x+C,
\end{equation}
for some constant $C$.
I am now stuck, instead of an expression for $f$ as a function of $x$, I have the other way round. Any advice on how can I arrive an expression for $f$ in terms of a series expansion in the form of eq.\eqref{1} to extract its coefficients $a_n$? Or is there any other trick to extract them? Maybe some further assumption or approximation will help?

The end result might be less as useful in finding an "easy" result.
Using
$$ \ln(f e^f - \sinh(f) ) - f  = 2 x + c_{1} $$
then
\begin{align}
\ln(f e^f - \sinh(f) ) + \ln(e^{-f})  &= 2 x + c_{1} \\
f - e^{-f} \, \sinh(f) &= c_{0} \, e^{2 x} \\
2 f - 1 + e^{-2 f} &= 2 \, c_{0} \, e^{2 x} \\
2 f + e^{-2 f} &= 1 + 2 \, c_{0} \, e^{2 x}. 
\end{align}
Now consider an equation of the form
$$ x + e^{-x} = u. $$
From this
\begin{align}
(x - u) + e^{-(x-u)} \, e^{-u} &= 0 \\
(x -u) \, e^{(x-u)} &= - e^{-u} \\
x-u &= W_{n}(- e^{-u}) \quad \text{ by use of the Lambert W function}
\end{align}
which gives the result
$$ x = u + W_{n}(- e^{-u}). $$
Returning to the $f$ equation the solution, $f(x)$, takes the form
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2} + c_{0} \, e^{2 x} + \frac{1}{2} \, W_{n}\left(- \exp(-1 -2 \, c_{0} \, e^{2 x}) \right). $$
Note that $c_{0} = \exp(c_{1}) = \text{constant}$ and the Lambert W function is
$$ x \, e^x = y \to x = W_{n}(y), $$
and $n$ is the branch chosen (typically $n \in \{ -1, 0, 1 \}$).

This solved the problem and moreover was clearly explained, thank you very much! Indeed the Lambert W function was the right tool to use. Just a last question: how can we identify the 'right' branch of the W function for this problem?
